# Is _mm_broadcast_ss faster than _mm_set1_ps?

Tags: vectorization, avx

Is this code

```
float a = ...;
__m256 b = _mm_broadcast_ss(&a)
```

always faster than this code

```
float a = ...;
_mm_set1_ps(a)
```

?

What if `a` defined as `static const float a = ...` rather than `float a = ...`?

Comment: I think that should be `__m128 b = _mm_broadcast_ss(&a)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mm_broadcast_ss is likely to be faster than mm_set1_ps. The former translates into a single instruction (VBROADCASTSS), while the latter is emulated using multiple instructions (probably a MOVSS followed by a shuffle). However, mm_broadcast_ss requires the AVX instruction set, while only SSE is required for mm_set1_ps.

Comment: Huh? `_mm_set1_ps` should be a single `shufps` instruction; assuming `_mm_broadcast_ss` actually generates a `vbroadcastss`, it may require a store if the value isn't already in memory (and it requires a load, so its latency is longer than a shuffle in the best case).  Even if `vbroadcastss` were faster, nothing would prevent the compiler from emitting `vbroadcastss` for the `_mm_set1_ps` intrinsic when AVX is enabled.

Comment: How would you implement it using just a single shuffle? You need to get the single float value into one of the SIMD registers before you can do the shuffle, which would take something like the MOVSS that I described. If comparing apples to apples, you would need to include that overhead. Your point about the compiler being free to emit VBROADCASTSS for _mm_set1_ps is correct if AVX is enabled. I'm not aware of whether any compilers of note actually do this, though.

Comment: The value being splatted is computed either at compile time or at runtime; if it's computed at compile time, then the compiler can either store it splatted (and use a simple vector load or the load-operand form of the instruction that consumes it), or can place it at known alignment and use the load operand form of `pshufd` to splat it, or use `vbroadcastss` (or one of several other options).  If the value is not a compile-time constant, then it needs to be computed and is probably already in an SSE/AVX register, ready to be consumed by `shufps`.

Answer (score 12):

_mm_broadcast_ss has weaknesses imposed by the architecture which are largely hidden by the *mm* SSE API.  The most important difference is as follows:

- _mm_broadcast_ss is limited to loading values from memory only.

What this means is if you use _mm_broadcast_ss explicitly in a situation where the source is not in memory then the result will likely be less efficient than that of using _mm_set1_ps.  This sort of situation typically happens when loading immediate values (constants), or when using the result of a recent calculation.  In those situations the result will be mapped to a register by the compiler.   To use the value for broadcast, the compiler must dump the value back to memory.  Alternatively, a pshufd could be used to splat directly from register instead.

_mm_set1_ps is implementation-defined rather than being mapped to a specific underlying cpu operation (instruction).  That means it might use one of several SSE instructions to perform the splat.  A smart compiler with AVX support enabled should definitely use vbroadcastss internally when appropriate, but it depends on the AVX implementation state of the compilers optimizer.

If you're very confident you're loading from memory -- such as iterating over an array of data -- then direct use of broadcast is fine.  But if there's any doubt at all, I would recommend stick with _mm_set1_ps.

And in the specific case of a `static const float`, you absolutely want to avoid using _mm_broadcast_ss().

Answer (score 8):

If you target AVX instruction set, gcc will use VBROADCASTSS to implement _mm_set1_ps intrinsic. Clang, however, will use two instructions (VMOVSS + VPSHUFD).

Comment: Thanks. I use Clang. Is there a good reason for Clang not use VBROADCASTSS?

Comment: No, it is just a compiler bug.