# AVX 256-bit equivalent for _mm_load1_ps

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx

With SSE you can load a single float from memory into all 4 slots of a __m128 with the intrinsic _mm_load1_ps()

When using 256 bit wide SIMD with AVX, there seems to be no _mm256_load1_ps() to load a single float from memory into all 8 slots of the vector.

Why is this omission, and what's the best way around this?

Or even better: is there a way to load a single float to a targeted slot 0..7 of the vector?

Comment: AVX and AVX2 still only allow you to insert elements into the low 128 (`PINSRD` / `INSERTPS`:  element number = compile-time constant).  Doing this without zeroing the upper128 is only possible with the non-VEX encoding, triggering a massive slowdown on Intel pre-Skylake from mixing VEX and non-VEX instructions.  You could extractf128, insertps, insertf128.

Comment: `_mm_load1_ps` is a composite intrinsic for `movss` + shuffle to broadcast a float.  If you were already willing to let the compiler do whatever it felt like to get a constant into a register, `_mm256_set1_ps(*f)` is a good choice.  Smart compilers will emit `VBROADCASTSS` where appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[_mm256_broadcast_ss](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_broadcast_ss.htm) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but why not do _mm256_set1_ps(*x)?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218391/is-mm-broadcast-ss-faster-than-mm-set1-ps

Comment: _mm256_set1_ps(*x) would work as well, but it can generate multiple instructions. _mm256_broadcast_ss is guaranteed to generate only one instruction, VBROADCASTSS