# difference between load1 and broadcast intrinsics

Tags: x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

What's the difference between `_mm_broadcast_ss()` and `_mm_load_ps1()`?

```
void example(){
   __declspec(align(32)) const float num = 20;

   __m128 a1 = _mm_broadcast_ss(&num); 
   __declspec(align(32)) float f1[4];
   _mm_store_ps (f1, a1);
   std::cout << f1[0] << " " << f1[1] <<" " << f1[2] << " " << f1[3] << "\n";

   __m128 a2 = _mm_load_ps1(&num); 
   __declspec(align(32)) float f2[4];
   _mm_store_ps (f2, a2);
    std::cout << f2[0] << " " << f2[1] <<" " << f2[2] << " " << f2[3] << "\n";
}
```

I got same output in both ways, so why do they both exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_mm_broadcast_ss` only compiles for AVX targets.

`_mm_load1_ps` / `_mm_load_ps1` will compile to multiple instructions (`movss` / `shufps`) when compiling for targets that don't support AVX.  When you *are* compiling for an AVX target, any good compiler will use a `vbroadcastss` to implement them.

`load1` / `set1` and other convenience functions were introduced early on, because it's often good to let the compiler pick the optimal strategy for moving data around.

`_mm_broadcast_*` intrinsics were introduced as direct wrappers around the `vbroadcastss` / `vbroadcastsd` instructions.  (AVX2 has integer `vpbroadcast...`, and the reg-reg forms of `vbroadcastss`.  AVX1 only has `vbroadcastss x/ymm, [mem]`.)

---

### AFAICT, there's no downside to just using `_mm_load1_ps` or `_mm_set1_ps`.

It makes no difference to the code, and lets the same source build for non-AVX targets.

The choice might make a difference to the asm output at `-O0`, but IDK.  If you care about the asm output in an un-optimized build, then 1: that's weird, and 2: you'll have to see what your compiler does.

---

As you can see from the asm output on godbolt (for gcc):

### [Without AVX](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQoksiqIA9gM54ICG65FIAZol0gPr8AggDUAGoLKD0ARgBMADiQAjCCyYAKCHTBMkXKHRbYAVAAcAlEgDeZJElwJsMXGAGZ%2By3Ebhqm%2FBgYNSwBuMgBfCgQwOG4yKX5ZRSRDFjgZLR09AyNTSxs7BycXN0T0flT0%2FjMg0Ij40B4EPkFRCX4yADc6EDgkBAAPNjMoBA0LW3skbV1sfVS5sBh0JABeJDkABjDCgUT5JRYZNfdyrx8%2FbACggDIl9AsQpF3dligQAHMwdQ0AZjkrDljPoZABtAAsAF0wlMygFsHRHNUGEgNFwZAAaJBHR67JhwABcBO0MDmKBQINBm0hqApACIkAzyZSZDTyQymRT0aC5Gz6YzaZTfnzGQAdMB0naw%2FbJFhyE5wyrIjJ3ZaPZ5TN6fb5Bf6Ahb6OQQ6G7OFMREIZGorhyLFy3FTJD4okkslco3UwUcwU20Gs2ne5m%2B3legVBo3Cr3iyX1YDRWJcIAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g6%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-Wall%20-march%3Dhaswell%20-mno-avx%22%7D%5D%7D) (`-mno-avx`)

```
bcast: compile error so I #ifdef it out

__m128 load1(const float*p) {  return _mm_load1_ps(p); }
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    shufps  xmm0, xmm0, 0
    ret
```

### [With AVX](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQoksiqIA9gM54ICG65FIAZol0gPr8AggDUAGoLKD0ARgBMADiQAjCCyYAKCHTBMkXKHRbYAVAAcAlEgDeZJElwJsMXGAGZ%2By3Ebhqm%2FBgYNSwBuMgBfCgQwOG4yKX5ZRSRDFjgZLR09AyNTSxs7BycXN0T0flT0%2FjMg0Ij40B4EPkFRCX4yADc6EDgkBAAPNjMoBA0LW3skbV1sfVS5sBh0JABeJDkABjDCgUT5JRYZNfdyrx8%2FbACggDIl9AsQpF3dligQAHMwdQ0AZjkrDljPoZABtAAsAF0wlMygFsHRHNUGEgNFwZAAaJBHR67JhwABcBO0MDmKBQINBm0hqApACIkAzyZSZDTyQymRT0aC5Gz6YzaZTfnzGQAdMB0naw%2FbJFhyE5wyrIjJ3ZaPZ5TN6fb5Bf6Ahb6OQQ6G7OFMREIZGorhyLFy3FTJD4okkslco3UwUcwU20Gs2ne5m%2B3legVBo3Cr3iyX1YDRWJcIAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g6%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-Wall%20-march%3Dhaswell%20-mavx%22%7D%5D%7D) (`-mavx`)

```
__m128 bcast(const float*p) { return _mm_broadcast_ss(p); }        
    vbroadcastss    xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    ret
__m128 load1(const float*p) {  return _mm_load1_ps(p); }
    vbroadcastss    xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    ret
```

Comment: Clang at one point was not a "good" compiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218391/is-mm-broadcast-ss-faster-than-mm-set1-ps/13222222#13222222 . I assume that's been fixed.